# Insert the data in phonegap database table?

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

In my application, i want to insert the value in the table. i have created the databse in **onDeviceReady()** method in the **index.html** file.

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Auto Generated with Sencha Architect -->
<!-- Modifications to this file will be overwritten. -->
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy, see www.w3.org">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Teritree</title>
<script type="text/javascript" id="phonegap" src=
"cordova-2.0.0.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="barcodescanner.js">
</script>

<script src="sencha-touch-all.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/Ext.ux.touch.Rating.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.Loader.setConfig({ disableCaching: false });
        Ext.Ajax.setDisableCaching(false);    

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var pictureSource;   // picture source
    var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 
    var mydb;

    // Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    }

    // PhoneGap is ready to be used!

    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("it is in ondevice ready method..");
        mydb = window.openDatabase("teritreeDb", "1.0", "TestDB", 10000);
        console.log("it is in ondevice ready method..1");
        mydb.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
        console.log("it is in ondevice ready method..2");
   }

   function populateDB(tx) {
   console.log("it is in populateDB----------1");
     tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO', function () {
         tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)', function () {
             console.log("Table created");
         });
     });

      // Transaction error callback
    //
    function errorCB(tx, err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err);
    }

    // Transaction success callback
    //
    function successCB() {
        alert("success!");
    }
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        if (!Ext.browser.is.WebKit) {
            alert("The current browser is unsupported.\n\nSupported browsers:\n" +
                "Google Chrome\n" +
                "Apple Safari\n" +
                "Mobile Safari (iOS)\n" +
                "Android Browser\n" +
                "BlackBerry Browser"
            );
        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i have one signup screen and there in the signup screen i have submit button. So if i click the submit button, all the details should store in the database means in the DEMO table..So in the controller, i am writing the button event,

```
     onSubmitButtonTap : function(button, e, options) {

        mydb = window.openDatabase("appDb", "1.0", "Test DB", 1000000);
        mydb.transaction(storeCustomerDetails, error, success);


    function storeCustomerDetails(tx)
    {
        tx.executeSql('insert into DEMO (id,data) values("1","Hello")');
        tx.executeSql('insert into DEMO (id,data) values("2","Hello World")');
    }

    function error(){
        alert("data is not inserted");
    }
    function success(){
        alert("data is succesfully inserted");
    }
},
```

but it is giving me the alert, data is not inserted.
I followed the link: [Phonegap DB Link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#openDatabase)

Please help..

Comment: which Phonegap version you using?

Comment: I checked in browser..db has been created..but table is not created

Comment: Still the same thing here..help please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cordova 2.0.0 and your issue will be solved.. You will be able to see the database you created in the file explorer. Do let me know if it helps you.

Comment: After adding 2.0, i am getting the issue..                           unable to resolve new-instance 159 (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;) in Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient;

Comment: Ok..And in xml folder, now only config.xml file is there. Because previously it was two files: plugins.xml and corodova.xml.  I removed those two and added config.xml

Comment: Ok..but now also, i am not able to see the log file..which i added in index.html file

Comment: I edited my index.html..you can see..but still not getting the logs and database also not created..

Comment: I dont see where you called onLoad() which will register the listener... Correct that....

Comment: i added..just check the code..it was there..                           // Wait for PhoneGap to connect with the device
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
    }

Comment: I know its there but its not called, put in your body like this `<body onload="onLoad()">`

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: errorCB is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:51

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14617/discussion-between-coder-slay-and-arindam-mukherjee)

Comment: mydb.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB); this line error

Answer (score 1):

Arindam, do not forget by default the executing of the sql is asyncronious. Therefore nobody  warranty your sqls will be executed in order you have defined in function populateDB(tx). Eg. it could execute first create than delete...

To be sure in the order you have to define subsequent calls in the callback function

```
function populateDB(tx) {
     tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO', function () {
         tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)', function () {
             console.log("Table created");
         });
     });
}
```

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: The problem is, i am not able to see the database in the file explorer in eclipse..And not even in tablet SD Card..

Comment: What does mean no luck? did you get 'Table created' message on my scenario?

Comment: No even i checked for the log message. But not found. So it means, database is not created??